# Multi-way split with CARTs

Tags: categorical-data, cart

I am predicting a categorical variable (Yes/No) called Company Failure. This depends on a range of input variables (financial ratios).

I am planning to convert a continuous variable (Liquidity Ratio) into an Ordinal Variable representing four groups (Say Unstable Liquidity, Moderate Liquidity, Stable Liquidity, High Liquidity)?

I am not sure if this can be used as an input to decision-trees? or should I create only two groups (to retain binary split which I have read is necessary)?

Answer (score 1):

CARTs treat ordinal variables just like continuous one, i.e. it will create binary splits like $\text{Liquidity}>\text{Moderate}$, $\text{Liquidity}<\text{High}$, etc.

BTW this way making such categorisation on your own is rather a bad idea -- better leave this to the CART algorithm to optimise.